# Product of self invertible elements is self invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove (or disprove) that given a group (G,*) with self invertible elements a and b, then the product of a and b also self invertible.

What I Know:
$a*a=e$ (where e is the identity element),

$b*b=e$

$*$ is associative

$*$ may not be commutative, but inverses by definition commute

The best I've come up with so far is assuming that the group is Abelian so that:
$(a*a)*(b*b)=e$,

$a*(a*b)*b=e$,

$(a*b)*(a*b)=e$,

But that seems like I'm assuming what I'm trying to prove.

I would appreciate any pointers. I feel like this is simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Good lord that formating.......

Answer (score 3):

Consider the group $S_3$, and the permutations $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$ as a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add on a way to see that this is false:

Since $a$ is the inverse of $a$ and $b$ is the inverse of $b$, we can write:

$$ab * ba = a*a = e$$

So $ab$ has inverse $ba$, and since not all groups are commutative, it will not hold in general that $ba = ab$ as the problem desires. (but it does hold true in Abelian groups, as you noticed. This, of course, is not enough to show it for all groups)

Carry on Smiling gave a good counterexample which you can explicitly use to disprove this.

Comment: nice ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

You noted that the property is true when $G$ is abelian. Also it is true "only if" every pair of involutions commute: assume that $a^2=1=b^ 2$ and $(ab)^2=1$, then $abab=1$, so (multiplying at the front with $a^{-1}$ and at the back with $b^{-1}$) this yields $ba=a^{-1}b^{-1}=ab$. So $a$ and $b$ commute.